# Docker image not pulling the latest image from Docker Hub using tag "latest" using Helm Chart

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Currently I implemented a test CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins, Docker and Kubernetes. I am using Kubernetes Helm Chart for adding my Kubernetes resources and using Dockerhub as image repository. When I am checking the output of api that I deployed, it's not updated with modified change.

When I checked with the console output of Jenkins, it showing everything successfully. But the latest Docker image is not pulling by using the tag "latest". Still I am getting the older output.

In my Helm Chart values.yaml, I added like following:

```
imageCredentials:
  name: helmchartrepository
  registry: <my-registry-name>
  username: <my-username>
  password: <my-password>

image:
  repository: <my-repository>
  tag: latest
  pullPolicy: Always
```

And my deployment.yaml referring to these values like the following:

[image]

NB: Even if I am using the configuration for pulling latest image from repository by using "latest" , still I am not getting the modified image. And there is no error also. Only issue is pulling the latest docker image from Dockerhub image repository.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we setup kubernetes to automatically change containers when a new one is pushed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629463/how-can-we-setup-kubernetes-to-automatically-change-containers-when-a-new-one-is)

Comment: Short answer: have Jenkins assign some unique tag per build (it knows the current commit ID and the current time), and then `helm upgrade --install --set image.tag=...` when you're deploying.  Don't use the `latest` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `date: "{{ .Release.Time.Seconds }}"` in your `deployment` under `template/metadata/labels` and set `imagePullPolicy: Always`. Helm will detect the changes in the deployment object and will pull the latest image each time:

```
template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.app.frontendName }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
        date: "{{ .Release.Time.Seconds }}"
```

Run `helm upgrade releaseName ./my-chart` to upgrade your release

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added the data like this. But still not getting the updated result.

Comment: @Jacob I have the same setup and it’s working. Not sure what’s the issue

Comment: After this change, no matter if a new image is updated or not. All the pod get recreated, this is same as `--recreate-pods` flag.  Is there a way to recreate a pod only if a new image is updated?

Answer (score 1):

Helm is not able to understand whether the image has been updated or not. Since you are using the fixed tag latest. You can add some labels like date or timestamp in the metadata to identify the change.

Answer (score 0):

In your `values.yaml` file, in your image, add `date` as following:

```
replicaCount: 3

image:
  repository: yourRepo/yourImage
  pullPolicy: Always
  tag: "yourTag"
  # Add this
  date: "{{ .Release.Time.Seconds }}"
```